# Send second source of audio to remote participant

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video-streaming, twilio

I'm trying to send a second source of audio (streamed from a bluetooth connected device as Int16 data flow) to a room using twilio-video on iOS.

I already looked at TVIAudioController but found nothing about audioInput.
Checked-out also TVIAudioSink but I don't know if it can do the job.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not an expert in this at all, but since no-one else has helped yet, I can try to point you in the right direction. It sounds like you're trying to hack around the limitation of using one microphone on an iOS device at a time. Good luck!

In order to send another audio track, you need to create a [`TVILocalAudioTrack`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.5/docs/Classes/TVILocalAudioTrack.html). Normally this is initialised using the `track` method, which picks the audio input itself. It's not recommended to use the regular initializer, but that is probably worth exploring.

Once you have your `TVILocalAudioTrack` you need to [add it to your room Participant using `addAudioTrack`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.5/docs/Classes/TVILocalParticipant.html#//api/name/addAudioTrack:).

Let me know if that helps at all.